# The concept of solid when it is used about the contribution of a paper

Tags: peer-review

My Question:

What does it mean when the reviewer wrote the following sentence

*The contribution is quite solid*

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/solid), meaning 4:

> of good substantial quality or kind

It's synonymous of *sound*.

Apparently, the reviewer thinks that your paper is good, constructed on "solid" grounds.